# How to check browser support playbackRate in source?

Tags: javascript, html, video, playback-rate

I am building a video controller capable of changing playbackRate.
However, some browsers that do not support the playbackRate function would like to display the message.
For example, "Not supported in this browser".

Is there a way to check if the playbackRate function is working properly in JavaScript?

Here's how I tried:

```
try{
    player.playbackRate = 0.95;
    // if check here : console.log(player.playbackRate) = 0.95 in not supported browser.

    if (player.playbackRate != 0.95) {
        alert('Not supported in this browser');
    }

    player.playbackRate = 1;
}
catch(e) {
    alert('Not supported in this browser');
}
```

However, even on browsers that do not support playbackRate, the actual playbackRate value has changed and no error or message has been output.

Is there any way I can?

I hope you can help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can't check if a native property exists, if you first add that property.

The way to check if a native property is supported, is generally to create a clean, new element, and see if it has that property *and* if the property value is what is expected

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio');

if ( 'playbackRate' in audio && audio.playbackRate === 1) {

    // is supported

}
```

Comment: Thanks adeneo.
It seems to be a good way to check if a property is supported.
However, the problem with the playbackRate property is that in some browsers the property exists and changes, but the actual playbackRate does not change at all.